# Web scraping requests python

Tags: python, authentication, session, python-requests

Good morning everyone, I'm trying to access the html code of a web page, I've got the login working through python but only that once I print the page the html code is not as complete as if I opened it in a browser...

```
loginurl = ('https://sgv.ivu-cloud.com/mbweb/j_security_check')
secure_url = ('https://sgv.ivu-cloud.com/mbweb/main/matter/desktop/main-menu')

session = HTMLSession()

payload = {
    'j_username' : creds.username,
    'j_password': creds.password
    }

s = requests.Session()
s.post(loginurl, data=payload)
r = s.get((secure_url), cookies={'from-my': 'browser'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
c = session.get('https://sgv.ivu-cloud.com/mbweb/main/matter/desktop/main-menu#duty-details?beginDate=2021-12-14&allocatedEmployeeId=22480')
d = s.get('https://sgv.ivu-cloud.com/mbweb/main/matter/desktop/main-menu#duty-details?beginDate=2021-12-14&allocatedEmployeeId=22480')



print(d)
```

a this is the answer:

```
    









IVU.plan Portal





        





































var mbwebBaseUrl = '/mbweb';
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/mbweb/struts/js/base/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/mbweb/struts/js/base/jquery-ui.min.js?s2j=4.0.3"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript"

                src="/mbweb/struts/i18n/datepicker-de.min.js?s2j=4.0.3"></script>






    $(function () {

        jQuery.struts2_jquery.version = "4.0.3";

        jQuery.struts2_jquery.loadAtOnce = true;

        jQuery.scriptPath = "/mbweb/struts/";

        jQuery.struts2_jquery.local = "de";

        jQuery.struts2_jquery.gridLocal = "de";

        jQuery.struts2_jquery.timeLocal = "de";

        jQuery.struts2_jquery.datatablesLocal = "de";

        jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;



        jQuery.ajaxSetup({

            cache: false

        });



        jQuery.struts2_jquery.require("js/struts2/jquery.ui.struts2.min.js?s2j=4.0.3");



    });


    <link id="jquery_theme_link" rel="stylesheet"

          href="/mbweb/struts/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css?s2j=4.0.3"

          type="text/css"/>
```

600

Comment: You can use selenium. The site is using js for the content of the page. So for loading the page you can use selenium. It will help you to get the page HTML as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your code to login and get the cookies.
then you can pass the cookies to selenium and continue

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="driver/geckodriver.exe")
for c in s.cookies:
    driver.add_cookie({'name': c.name, 'value': c.value})

driver.get('https://sgv.ivu-cloud.com/mbweb/main/matter/desktop/main-menu#duty-details?beginDate=2021-12-14&allocatedEmployeeId=22480')
```

this will only work if you have logged-in first using your code, so this needs to be added to your code in the end

Comment: I have to change the values in the string? (driver.add_cookie({'name': c.name, 'value': c.value})), if I execute the code as you wrote it I get this error :  arserError: 
Line |
   1 |      driver.add_cookie({'name': c.name, 'value': c.value})
     |                               ~
     | Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.